# Correct file hierarchy for document generation

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to go through the process of contributing a package to the ROS community. From what I've gleaned from various tutorials (like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation)), a common practice is to create a GitHub account, and create a repository named *whatever*-ros-pkg. Inside that repository, each directory contains a package (or metapackage). Two questions:

1. The root level of that repository itself does not represent a ROS package or metapackage, correct? Catkin appears to be displeased when you try to make it one, as the naming convention isn't correct (hyphens instead of underscores).
2. If my assumption in (1) is correct, then what should I put in the distribution.yaml file for a given ROS distro? Would I put this:

   whatever-ros-pkg:
   doc:
   type: git
   url: https://github.com/username/whatever-ros-pkg.git
   version: hydro-devel

...or do I need to add every package within the repository and give them the same Git URL? Will the indexer pick up the repo and its constituent packages as it's currently written?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148726/correct-file-hierarchy-for-document-generation/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The layout of the packages in a repository is not fixed. You can place a single package into the root of the repo (e.g. https://github.com/ros/genmsg) or you can put packages under a hierarchy of folders (e.g. https://github.com/ros/ros_comm).

The folder name / repository does not have to be identical to the containing package name but usually that is a good idea since that is what a user would usually expect.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look [distribution.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/distribution.yaml) for the format of an existing multi-package repo (e.g. [navigation](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation)).

1). Correct, all the packages (including metapackages) should be subdirs.

2. bloom-release should generate the correct pull request for you, you just need to make sure your repo is set up correctly.

   doc:
   type: git
   url: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git
   version: hydro-devel
   release:
   packages:

   - amcl
   - base_local_planner
   - carrot_planner
   - clear_costmap_recovery
   - costmap_2d
   - dwa_local_planner
   - fake_localization
   - global_planner
   - map_server
   - move_base
   - move_base_msgs
   - move_slow_and_clear
   - nav_core
   - navfn
   - navigation
   - robot_pose_ekf
   - rotate_recovery
   - voxel_grid
     tags:
     release: release/hydro/{package}/{version}
     url: https://github.com/ros-gbp/navigation-release.git
     version: 1.11.6-1
     source:
     type: git
     url: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git
     version: hydro-devel

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1